# Regular Expressions in Elasticsearch/Kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, field, kibana

I only want to retrieve events that match my regular expression for a particular field. For example, events that have an IP address. Elastic doesn't support PCRE so is there a way I can achieve this from their supported regular expression syntax?

Here is the regex I had before discovering it was not supported by Elastic:
https://regex101.com/r/99b6dn/3

Here is what I attempted using Elastic's supported syntax, but it's not working:

```
/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/
```

Expected result would be `myfield:/<myregex>/` returning only logs that match the regex.

Comment: My bad. Edited post.

Comment: Using regex to search in elasticsearch should be the last resort. You should relook how you are indexing the document. You should rather extract information out of logs and index them as a structured document

Answer (score 1):

Only the non-capture group `(?: )` in your pattern is absent from the list of [supported regex operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html). Try:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

The query should look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "path": {
        "query": "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or a more accurate pattern

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```